# How to manually set the subsection number

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs

Is there a way to start the page with a 5.2 subsection:

```
5.2 Section
 5.2.5 Subsection
 5.2.6 Subsection
```

Otherwise, i get the 1 section and 0.1 subsection, which i don't need. Is there a package or a trick of some kind?

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! `\setcounter{section}{4}\section{Section}\setcounter{subsection}{1}\subsection{Subsection}\setcounter{subsubsection}{4}\subsubsection{Subsubsection}` (assuming that that is subsubsection, but you can change the counter names yourself I think).

Answer (score 8):

> Is there a way to start the page with a 5.2 subsection?

How about

```
\clearpage % start a new page here
\setcounter{section}{5}
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
\subsection{Hello World} % increments 'subsection' counter automatically (to "2")
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you would like to arbitrarily set numbering for subsection, here is my solution

```latex
\newcommand{\asubsection}[2]{
\setcounter{subsection}{#1}
\addtocounter{subsection}{-1}
\subsection{#2}
}
```

Then as following, assign any number for your subsection as you wish

```latex
\asubsection{3}{The Dirac Field}
\label{TDF}
...
\asection{12}{The Renormalization Group}
... Also read subsection \ref{TDF}.
```

The output is as following

> [image: arbitrary subsection numbering]

We could see the cross reference `\ref{TDF}` and equation numbering are using the **correct** subsection number.

Comment: Is this fundamentally different to Mico's version about `\setcounter`?

Comment: In this way here, we could set arbitrary to any subsection, not only the first one. While Mico's way sets where to start, the following subsections will increase its numbering without being controlled.

Comment: Well, the control is the user's decision, which numbers should follow. Also, `\eqref` is usually not designed to refer to structure levels

Comment: What would we use then for referring a section? Thanks!

Comment: `\eqref` is a `amsmath` invention, but `\ref` is the cross-referencing macro